# Add custom script in `views.py` in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I just started working on Python using Django! I was referring to some video where they showed how to display content in the browser.

In `views.py`...

1. directly using `HttpResponse`

   ```
   from django.http import HttpResponse

   # Create your views here.
   def say_hello(request):
       return HttpResponse('Hello')
   ```
2. Using a custom template (HTML)

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import render

   # Create your views here.
   def say_hello(request):
       return render(request, 'hello.html')
   ```

I have my own Python script, which is `myscript.py` (in the root folder).
How can I run this script in `views.py`?

Comment: What are you asking for? I don't really understand your question

Comment: Can i add own script or function in views.py like 

Def say_hello(request):
  My customcode /my function

Comment: You want to add hello.html to your views.py?

Comment: No ! that i can able to do ! i want to include 'myscript.py' !

Comment: And what is that script for? Is it necesary to compile your code? Does your code work fine with what you have right now?

Comment: i am trying to display some content from myscript.py ! can't we render the template from python file like we render from html file ?

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you mean. Could you update your question adding the `myscript.py` so I can see what is what you cant to render?

Comment: @Linux assuming that my file myscript.py have just a welcome message ! 

Print("welcome user") , i want to display this instead of 
"
def say_hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello')  
"

This

Comment: @Linux getting error  "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playground.script' ! "(playground is my app name )

Answer (score 1):

Let's see how I would aproach this.

```
#myscript.py
print("Welcome user!")
```

We should change this to something like this:

```
#myscript.py
def run_script():
   return ("Welcome user!")
```

Then in your `views.py` you have to import `myscript.py`:

```
#views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .script import run_script # Import your script like this

def say_hello(request):
    script_output = run_script()
    # Return the script's output in the HttpResponse
    return HttpResponse(script_output)
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playground.script' ! (playground is my app name )

Comment: Could you add the structure of your project?